# count distinct-values

Tags: xml, count, xquery

Can you tell me how to put a comma in the following code within the count(distinct-values()) function so that it shows in the XQuery Output? Here's the code

```
Manschaften

{
for $m  in /Fussballmeisterschaft/Manschaften 

return
Tabelle

    {$m  /Namen/text()}
    {$m  /Punkte/text()}
    {
    for $t in Fussballmeisterschaft/Tabelle
    where $t/Manschaft = $m/Namen
        return
        count( distinct-values ($t//../Manschaft/text()))
    }   
    </Tabelle>
}
/Manschaften
```

and here's the output

```
:
>      
     Borussia Dortmund63
     FC Bayern Muenchen    60
     FC Schalke 0454
    Borussia Moenchengladbach51
    Hannover 9641
.........
```

This numbers behind the names of the teams are the points. So how to add a comma or space them?

Thaankkkkkksssssss :P

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  let $res := 
    for $t in Fussballmeisterschaft/Tabelle
    where $t/Manschaft = $m/Namen
    return count( distinct-values ($t//../Manschaft/text()))
  return fn:string-join($res, ', ')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing:

```
count(distinct-values($t//../Manschaft/text()))
```

to:

```
(count(distinct-values($t//../Manschaft/text())),',')
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Tabelle>
    {$m  /Namen/text(),","}
    {$m  /Punkte/text()}`
I did it ! it was in the declaration of the Namen and Punkte